# How can I direct open a *.html file in Visual Studio 2012/2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to open a html file in my ASP.NET MVC project from the Solution Explorer in my Visual Studio 2013.  But I want to open this file in the "Web Browser" within the Visual Studio. Does anyone know how to do this?

By the way, the "Web Browser" window can be opened by Visual Studio menu: [View] / [Other Window] / [Web Browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the HTML file you'd like to open and select `Browse With...` in the context menu. Select the `Internal Web Browser`.

[image]